# How to terminate binary counting using a logic gate

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, counter, decoder, ripple-counter

So I am designing a 3-bit asynchronous binary counter which counts up to 11 then repeats using D flip-flops. That much I have done, however I am stuck when it comes to decoding the outputs to stop the counting sequence. I am only supposed to use one logic gate, though. I was thinking of how I could do this using an actual decoder, but I am completely lost when it comes to using just one gate. Any tips to get going? I want to actually figure this out.

Comment: How does an asynchronous counter work? It just counts as fast as it can, with no clock input?

Comment: That's right, there is no clock.

Comment: So the D flip flops have no clock input?

Comment: They do, but they are connected to the output of the previous flip flop.

Comment: I would have have posted a schematic if I had the ability to but I don't right now unfortunately, so sorry about the vagueness.

Comment: I think you better post a schematic, somehow. A link to a picture or something.

Comment: Use the built in schematic editor on this website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't count to 11 on 3 bits, so I presume you're actually using 4 bits.  What you need to do is AND the two highest bits together, and feed that into the async reset of all 4 flip flops.  This will reset the counter back to 0 very shortly after it reaches 12.